# How start new billing circle in braintree

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, braintree, recurring-billing

I use recurring payment in Braintree and there is a function for user to ON\Off the automatic paying everymonth.

The problem is, how could I start new billing when user off then on again ?
E.g. if user off the auto billing on 30th this month and on again on 15 next month, looks like the billing still count from 30th? While the right way should be starting to charge them from 15th next month!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The best way to achieve this is to [cancel the customer's subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/cancel/) set for the 30th and then [create a new subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/#billing_day_of_month) with a `billing_day_of_month` set for the 15th. The Braintree Articles site has more information on the [recurring billing](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview) feature.

Comment: Then how could this process be programmable ? Because we have many users. Cannot every time go to check and manually change it?

Comment: Recurring billing is something that everyone does differently. The api provides the basic building blocks that let you do almost anything you need, but each case is different. If this is truly custom then you could consider writing your own billing scripts that don't use subscription.